# Find node in Zookeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I want to know if there is a way to walk the Zookeeper's (ZK) in memory database and find if any particular node exists. Something similar to `find . -name file` inside ZK

I am logged in to ZK using zkCli.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have your ZK cluster running, you can connect to a node and query the cluster.
For example:

```
$ZK_HOME/bin/zkCli.sh -server localhost
```

List of nodes:

```
ls /
```

List of commands:

```
?
```